# Boolean Include Task Canceled Exception while doing Parallel.Foreach in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, parallel.foreach

I have an odd situation where I'm not able to locate the source of my error for the following stacktrace:

```
Message :One or more errors occurred.<br/>
StackTrace :   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body)
```

The Code itself is a plain and simple Parallel.Foreach loop with some logic like following:

```
Parllel.Foreach(_collection, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism =5 }, item=>
{
// code inside
});
```

What could be the source of this issue ? Do you guys have any tips for me where should I look for?

@mortb  this is how I log the stacktrace exception:

```
  string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Error.txt";

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Message :" + ex.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace +
                   "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

Comment: Debug and take a look at the thrown exceptions property `InnerExceptions` (note the s in `InnerExceptions`) The outer exception is just a wrapper over one or several exceptions thrown by "`// code inside`" the actual exceptions are listed in `InnerExceptions`

Comment: @mortb this is what's bugging me .. I'm not able to write the exception into the text file... Hold on I'll show you how I log the error..

Comment: @mortb can you see my updated question ? That's how I log the exception itself... Is there any way that I can log the inner exception itself and to see which line throws it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposed changes to logging:

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Error.txt";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{
      foreach(var inner in (ex as AggregateException).?InnerExceptions ?? (new [] {ex}))
      {
           writer.WriteLine("Message :" + inner.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + inner.StackTrace +
           "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
           writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
      }
}
```

Comment: Mortb, thank you so much !! Gonna try the code now :)

Comment: it says the  ex. doesn't contains property named InnerExceptions, rather just 1 property in singuar form called "InnerException"

Comment: Probably you have caught the exception as `catch (Exception ex)` and then it has lost its type, I added code to cast it to AggregateException (not tested) The code is not optimal, but it might work

Answer (score 1):

Your `// code inside` is throwing a exception. The exception you see is the `Parallel.For` loop killing its worker tasks to shutdown properly. Normally the `ForEach` function should throw a exception in the end that holds the actual reason for the error. The error you see looks like the debugger triggering on a inner exception of the `ForEach` function.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply! I've updated my initial question with how I log the exception itself... Is there any way that i can log the inner exception itself ?

Comment: The type of the exception should be a `AggregateException`. If you cast to this one you get a property `InnerExceptions` (note the "s"). One of the exceptions in this list is the one you are looking for.